# How can I restore the Time and Date to the panel?

Tags: unity, indicator, time

After upgrading to Saucy Salamander which I think is v 13.10 my date and time usually  disappears after boot up. I have seen some solutions on older questions one of which is:
Using the terminal type

> killall unity-panel-service

which works temporarily but problem returns after reboot.

I know this question has been asked before so I could add to that discussion however I found that thread confusing. Any ideas?
Matt

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to this bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1199877

Short answer, just enable proposed updates and update unity panel service and gtk3.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. Just to clarify, are you saying that this is caused by the unity-panel-service using all the memory and the cpu as described in Bug #1199877 ?

Comment: Before I installed the proposed updates the panel was freezing and 50% of the time i turned on the computed I had to restart because the clock didn't appear to me not even restarting the unity panel.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have just rebooted and the timedate appears in the panel. I can't see a problem with cpu usage. Maybe intermittant, so I'll boot a few times and see.